Harmonic function in half-disk
I'm studying for qualifying exam and was struggling with this problem. Thanks for any help!
Let $\Omega$ be the half-disk $\{ z = x+iy : x > 0, |z| < 1\}$. Let $u$ be the bounded harmonic function on $\Omega$ that has boundary value $1$ on the vertical open segment $(-i,i)$ and has boundary value $0$ on the open circular arc $\{ |z| = 1, x >0\}$. What is the value of $u(\frac{1}{2})$?
I thougth about finding a conformal map $f$ from a unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ to a half-disk $\Omega$ that maps $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ and then applying mean-value theorem to the function $u(f(z))$:
$$u\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = u(f(0)) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(f(e^{it})) dt.$$
We know the value of $u$ on the boundary, so knowing $f$ we would be able to compute the integral. But I am not sure whether it is possible to apply here mean-value theorem since $u$ is not continuous on the boundary.

Since your function is of special type there is a simple way. I got ${1\over \pi}\arctan 2$ but the steps are not properly justified.  This may be helpful.

@RyszardSzwarc: I got a slightly different value, hopefully it is correct.

The harmonic function $u$ can be determined with some simple geometric considerations.
Let $\alpha(z)$ be the angle under which the segment $[-1, 1]$ is seen from the point $z$:

That is a harmonic function of $z$ because both $\arg(z-i)$ and $\arg(z+i)$ are harmonic as the imaginary parts of a logarithm.
Also $\alpha(z)$ approaches $\pi$ if $z$ approaches a point on the open segment $(-i, i)$, and $\alpha(z)$ approaches $\pi/2$ if $z$ approaches a point on the semicircle, the latter is Thales's theorem. Therefore
$$
 u(z) = \frac 2 \pi \alpha(z) - 1
$$
is the harmonic function with the prescribed boundary values, and
$$
 \alpha\left( \frac 12 \right) = 2 \arctan 2 \\
\implies u\left( \frac 12 \right) = \frac 4 \pi \arctan 2 - 1 \approx 0.4096655 \, .
$$

Nice solution (+)

This is really nice solution! Thank you!
